# extracting hour and minutes from a cell in pandas column

Tags: pandas, time

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBVNq.png)

How can I split or extract 04:38 from 04:38:00 AM in a pandas dataframe column?

Comment: Are your input hours always two digits?  Then you can use string slicing, otherwise you will need to use regex.

Comment: The right way is probably convert them to timestamp and then extract the hour and minute components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df.timestamp
3   2020-01-17 07:02:20.540540416
2   2020-01-24 01:10:37.837837824
7   2020-03-14 21:58:55.135135232
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%H:%M')
3    07:02
2    01:10
7    21:58
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html?highlight=dt%20strftime#pandas.Series.dt.strftime

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.slice`:

```py
df["hm"] = df["time"].str.slice(stop=5)
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and straight forward.